# i m trying to run this but it showing me error path.split is not a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run this in react but it showing me error:

> path.split is not a function

```
import React from 'react'
import './SendMail.css'
import  CloseIcon  from '@material-ui/icons/Close'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

function SendMail() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
       console.log(data)
    } 

    return (
        <div className="sendMail">
            <div className="sendMail_header">
                <h3>New Message</h3>
                <CloseIcon className="sendMail_close"/>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <input
                 name='to'
                 placeholder="To"
                 type="text"
                 ref = {register({required:true})}
               />
                <input
                 name='subject'
                 placeholder="Subject"
                 type="text"
                                                
                />
                <input
                 name='message'               
                 placeholder="Message.."
                 type="text"
                 className="sendMail_message"
                                  
                 />

                <div className="sendMail_options">
                    <Button className="sendMail_send"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    >
                    Send
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Export default SendMail

[image]

Comment: it must be in another component, since this is not contain the words `path.split`

Comment: plz describe it

Comment: check which component causes the error, and share it. (if you can't check it, share image of the error)

Comment: when i use ref={register({required:true})} then they show ne error

Comment: ref={register({ required: true })} this one

Comment: edit your question

Comment: actually i m not add image becoz of less repositary

Comment: now it is working i m using this right now

Comment: {...register('to', { required: true })}